# PHPExcel renaming default worksheet name to another name

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am using **PHPExcel** to export my files from database, but my problem is when I download my excel the name of my sheet is the default "Worksheet". I would like to set it to another name like *"Hello world"*.

Here's my code so far

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('A1', '1')
    ->setCellValue('B1', '2')
    ->setCellValue('C1', '3')
    ->setCellValue('D1', '4')
    ->setCellValue('E1', '5')
    ->setCellValue('F1', '6')
    ->setCellValue('G1', '7')
    ->setCellValue('H1', '8')
    ->setCellValue('I1', '9')
    ->setCellValue('J1', '10');
$row = 2; 
while($rowz = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $col = 0;
    foreach($rowz as $key=>$value) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
        $col++;
    }
    $row++;
}
```

How am I able to set the new title for my worksheet? Thanks!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can set the title like so:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Title");
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way to rename another sheet? For example, the third one?